# javascript regexp for these special chars

Tags: javascript, regex

What's the best way to check an input field in javascript against special chars ? regexp ? if so then how can I check for the next bunch of chars:

```
~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{[]\/?><:"`;'.,
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you *want* these characters or do you *not* want them?

Comment: C'mon, show some research efforts. Any regular expressions tutorial would have helped you. Example: http://regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/[~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{[\]\\\/?><:"`;.,']/
```

(Notice the escaping for closing bracket, backslash, and slash delimiter with backslash)

Then use the [RegExp `test` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) on your input string.

Answer (score 1):

```
/([!"#\$%&'\(\)\*\+,\.\/:;<=>\?@\[\\\]\^`\{\|\}~])/g
```

If you want to remove these characters...

```
function removeBaddies(value) {
    return value.replace(/([!"#\$%&'\(\)\*\+,\.\/:;<=>\?@\[\\\]\^`\{\|\}~])/g, '');
}
```

Comment: Why so many backslashes?

Comment: I use visual studio and it messes up the intellisense and auto-formatting if you don't escape them properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match the special characters, then use them inside a `[]`.

```
[~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{[\]\\/?><:"`;'.,]
```

If you don't need them, then add a `caret(^)` at the start of the list.

```
[^~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{[\]\\/?><:"`;'.,]
```